# Dynamic State variable in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I have state like below

```
state= {
        editnameEnable: false,
        editemailEnable: false,
        editaddressEnable: false,
        edittelephone_noEnable: false,
}
```

I have JSX code like below

```
<td>
    {this.state.edit[ name or address or email or telephone_no ]Enable? <input type="text"/> : <input type="text"/> } 
</td>
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I know what you're asking but I think in part you could use template strings. With the ` and ${} syntax.

Comment: Thanks @JoeLloyd. Your solution is not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could have a more clear design in your scenario,
though, this is what you can do:

```
this.state[`edit${_variable_}Enable`]
```

Comment: Thanks @Carr. Your solution is working. Thanks.